# Создать пирамиду из чисел в питоне

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать код в питоне, используя while nested loop, чтобы получить паттерн как на фото.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написала код, но в output не получается ровная пирамида.

```
i = 0
num = 5
while i<6:
    k=8
    j=0
    num=5
    while j<6:
        if num - i > 0:
            print("  " , end=" ")
        else:
            print(k,end=" ")
        k+=1
        j+=1
        num=num-1
    print()
    i+=1
```

Результат:

```
               13 
            12 13 
         11 12 13 
      10 11 12 13 
   9 10 11 12 13 
8 9 10 11 12 13
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если число меньше 10, то в тех колонках, где его не нужно еще выводить, печатайте всего один пробел, ведь именно столько число будет занимать:

```
if num - i > 0:
    if k < 10:
      print(" " , end=" ")
    else:
      print("  " , end=" ")
else:
    print(k,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант - заменить строчку вывода пробелов

```
print("  ", end=" ")
```

На такую, чтобы число выводимых пробелов соответствовало кол-ву цифр в числе:

```
print(" " * len(str(k)), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```py
mini, maxi = 8, 13
i = maxi
delta = 13 
while i >= mini:
    j = i
    print(" " * delta, end="")
    while j <= maxi:
        print(j, end=" ")
        j += 1
    print()
    i -= 1
    delta -= len(str(i)) + 1
```

Вывод:

```
             13 
          12 13 
       11 12 13 
    10 11 12 13 
  9 10 11 12 13 
8 9 10 11 12 13
```